# Python asyncua connection to OPCUA server with username and password

Tags: python, python-asyncio, opc-ua

I am trying to connect to OPC UA with only username and password.
I am using library for Python `asyncua` version `1.0.4`

Below part snip of my code:

```
async with Client(url=self._url, timeout=2) as client:
      # client.activate_session(username="guest", password="guest")
      await client.set_user("guest")
      await client.set_password("guest")
```

I have checked different option but getting still error:
`The user identity token is not valid.(BadIdentityTokenInvalid)`

UaExpert is connecting with username and password without any problems.

Could anyone advise me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are connecting to the server before setting the password, change your code to this:

```
client = Client(url=self._url, timeout=2)
client.set_user("guest")
client.set_password("guest") 
async with client :
     # Do your sutff
```